# scan more than 10 barcodes in one bitmap using ML Kit Barcode Scanning

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I am using Google Ml Kit on Android to process bitmaps of scanned student tests with barcodes that has a lot of codes on them evrything works well except that it gets back always not more than 10 barcode even if there are 40 on one bitmap, is there a way to change detector options to get more than 10 detected?

```
  override fun detectInImage(image: InputImage): Task<List<Barcode>> {
    return barcodeScanner.process(image)
  }

  override fun onSuccess(barcodes: List<Barcode>, graphicOverlay: GraphicOverlay) {
    if (barcodes.isEmpty()) {
      Log.v(MANUAL_TESTING_LOG, "No barcode has been detected")
    }
    for (i in barcodes.indices) {
      graphicOverlay.add(BarcodeGraphic(graphicOverlay, barcode))
      logExtrasForTesting(barcode)
    }
  }
```

the size of barcodes is never larger than 10

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmWIJ.jpg)

Comment: You should provide the code and the bitmaps - assuming you're currently just testing the code and the bitmaps are also dummy data.

Comment: It mentions on this page that each API call is limited to 10 barcodes https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning